# Looping/Null Error while calling method from other class

Tags: java

Hey I want to call a Method from the home class, the problem is that if I call both classes from each other they will loop.

This is the code in the home class:

```
Shop shop_class = new Shop();
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[4];
//BUTTONS GET ADDET TO A PANEL THAT IS ON A FRAME


buttons[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(stbl + act + "shop button");
            
        shop_class.setVisible(true);
        home_close();
    }
});



private void home_close() {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public void home_open() {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
        buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Shop class:

```
    Shop shop_class = new Shop();

    buttons[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(stbl + act + "zurück button");
            
        setVisible(false);
        home_class.home_open();

    }});
```

Comment: You're missing methods. Surely this code is not just floating inside of the 'home' class. And what is 'buttons' and where/how is it declared? That's going to be important since you seem to be referring to it in the 'shop' class as well.

Comment: I addet it to the code, the buttons are addet to the panel, the panel is addet to the frame. if i switch to the shop page, a panel overlays the frame from the home class, so the buttons need to get deactivated. if i go back i have to reactivate the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buttons` only exists inside of Home -- you can't reference it from a Shop instance. Any logic to interact with the `buttons` array needs to be exposed via methods.

The code you provided shouldn't even compile because `buttons` is "invisible" to shop.

---

In a comment you said:

> If I switch to the shop page, a panel overlays the frame from the home class so the buttons need to get deactivated. If I go back, I have to reactivate the buttons.

You'd want to do something like this:

```
class Home {

    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[4];

    public void setButtonActiveState(boolean isActive) {
        for (JButton button : buttons) {
            button.setEnabled(isActive);
        }
    }

    // this is whatever your 'setup' method is that is adding all of the listeners
    public void setup() {
        // notice, passing a reference to Home to shop.
        Shop shop = new Shop(this);

        buttons[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                shop.setVisible(true);

                setButtonActiveState(false);
            }
        });
    }
}

class Shop {

    // a reference to home
    private final Home home;
    public Shop(Home home) {
        this.home = home;
    }

    // call this method when you close Shop
    void onClose() {

        // reactivate the home buttons
        this.home.setButtonActiveState(true);

    }
}
```

Basically, Shop needs to know about Home -- but it must not create a *new* Home ... there's already a Home instance so we should just reuse that. I did this by passing the Home instance to Shop in the constructor.

when Shop is closed, invoke the `onClose` method, which will then set the active state of the buttons in Home. Since the structure of Shop is a mystery, you'll need to apply that to the button or other closing mechanism (eg. keypress) yourself.

I also renamed your methods and variables: in Java you should use camelCase, not snake_case. Further you only need one method to toggle between button states, not two, since the only difference is a boolean variable.

Comment: thx <3 you are the best